# Determine Computability of Joint and Conditional Probabilities Given Few Tables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

### Problem

I've encountered the following problem during the introduction lecture of my Machine Learning class. I haven't taken a formal probability course yet, so any help would be appreciated.

---

Consider the multi-valued, random variables:
C (campus), G (grade), M (major), and Y (year).

*None of these variables are independent.* Given the probability tables for the following joint, marginal, and conditional probabilities, explain how to compute each probability below given the probabilities from above, or write “impossible.”

$P(Y)$, $P(M)$, $P(G,Y)$, $P(C|Y)$, $P(C,M)$, $P(Y|M)$

### Attempt

I'm unsure as to how to combine the given probabilities to derive $P(G | C, M)$ (#2) and what to specify for $P(C=main | Y=freshman)$ given the table for $P(C|Y)$ (#3). Does the order of joint and conditional probabilities matter?

1. P(M=compSci, Y=sophomore) = $P(Y|M)P(Y)$
2. P(G=B | C=LC, M=business) = ?
3. P(C=main | Y=freshman) = ?
4. P(G=B, M=bio) = *not possible*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (2), the only information about $G$ that you have is $P(G,Y)$, which does not give you any information about the dependence between $G$ and $(C,M)$. So this is impossible.

For (3), you already have the table for $P(C \mid Y)$, so $P(C=\text{main} \mid Y=\text{freshman})$ is one entry in this table.

Comment: Ah, makes sense! By the same reasoning for (2), (4) would also be impossible, correct? And (1) can be derived from the givens.

Comment: @AnthonyKrivonos Yes I believe so.